# Latency with NSURLConnection due to DNS lookups?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm banging my head here trying to figure out why there is a three to four second overheard for when an NSURLConnection object is created with a POST based NSMutableURLRequest. The overhead which I speak of, is after an NSURLConnection gets fired off, watching Apache access logs, I see the request come in substantially longer after invoking the request. On any other platform, I'd troubleshoot the latency that it takes to resolve DNS before going further. I shouldn't exclude the iPhone in this case as well. Has anyone else noticed similar behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds plausible that DNS is your bottleneck. Try making the request by address instead of name - at least for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Is DNS a known bottleneck for the iPhone. I've noticed this as well on my 3G connection. Did you workaround the problem by using the address instead of the hostname?

Comment: Since this doesn't actually answer the question, you should post it as a comment on the question, not as an answer.